# linear gradient is not working in IE background:linear-gradient(#83d7ff,#93ddfe,#e6f7fe,#fefefc);

Tags: css

```
background:linear-gradient(#83d7ff,#93ddfe,#e6f7fe,#fefefc);
```

The above code is working in chrome and other browsers but not IE

```
background:linear-gradient(#83d7ff,#93ddfe,#e6f7fe,#fefefc);
```

Comment: what version of IE?

Answer (score -1):

For IE you will need to use the filter method as shown below.

```
background: #f0f9ff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f9ff 0%, #cbebff 47%, #a1dbff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 47%,#a1dbff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 47%,#a1dbff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f9ff', endColorstr='#a1dbff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

To make your life easier use a gradient generator.